# If there is data linked to an order number, how do i pull some but not the other (not exists?)?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I'm using Toad for Oracle.

I currently have Order Numbers with items in both our yard and our warehouse. I'm looking to see items that ONLY have items in the yard.

Essentially I need a count of the different items in the yard and a sum of their weight for each order

I currently have it where it's counting the items for each order that are in the yard but it's not limiting it to orders that ONLY have yard items

```
select ORD.WH_ID, SIO.ORDER_NUMBER, SIO.CUSTOMER_NAME, COUNT    (ORD.ITEM_NUMBER) AS LINE_COUNT, SUM(TIM.UNIT_WEIGHT * ORD.QTY) AS WEIGHT
from t_ORDER_DETAIL ORD
JOIN T_ITEM_MASTER TIM
ON ORD.WH_ID = TIM.WH_ID
AND ORD.ITEM_NUMBER = TIM.ITEM_NUMBER
JOIN SI_ORDER SIO
ON SIO.WH_ID = ORD.WH_ID
AND SIO.ORDER_NUMBER = ORD.ORDER_NUMBER
where ORD.wh_id = '603'
--AND ORDER_NUMBER = '1923421'
AND PROCESS_DATE >= SYSDATE -1
AND TIM.CLASS_ID IN ('GYARD','GSSPIPE','GBLKALLTHR','GCOPPPIPE','GCOPPCNC')
AND SIO.CARRIER = 'OT'
GROUP BY ORD.WH_ID, SIO.ORDER_NUMBER, SIO.CUSTOMER_NAME, WEIGHT
ORDER BY SIO.ORDER_NUMBER

table 1
order #   Item #
Order1         Y51
Order1         Y52
Order2         Y51
Order2         W35
Order3         W21
Order3         W80

Table 2
Item #       Location
Y51          Yard
Y52          Yard
W35          Warehouse
W21          Warehouse
W80          Warehouse
```

From the above sample set, I would only want to see Order1 because it is the only order that contains ONLY items located in the Yard

Comment: Hi.  Please post a [mcve] with table definition and sample data and expected output.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand that about items in the yard and warehouse. It is the orders that tell me whether an item is in the in the yard and/or the warehouse? And what column tells me whether it's yard or warehouse? And the result would be a list of items that are in the yard and not in the warehouse? Each row with the item number, how many of it are in the yard, and their total weight?

Comment: I don't understand, you apparently know how to join tables so why are you not joining against the table with the location info as well, could you clarify what the problem is? I would also remove `WEIGHT` from the `GROUP BY`clause.

Comment: The issue that i'm having is that I still am seeing orders that include both yard and warehouse items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using your two sample tables (table 1 = orders, table 2 = items). This is how to find the order numbers of orders that contain yard items but no warehouse itms:

```
select o.orderno
from orders o
join items i on i.itemno = o.itemno
group by o.orderno
having count(case when i.location = 'Yard' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when i.location = 'Warehouse' then 1 end) = 0;
```

If you want to show complete orders, use above query in a subquery, e.g.:

```
select *
from orders
where orderno in ( <above query> )
order by orderno, itemno;
```

If you want an aggregation per order instead, you can modify the query accordingly, e.g.:

```
select
  o.orderno,
  count(*) as number_of_positions,
  sum(o.amount) as number_of_pieces,
  sum(o.amount * i.weight) as total_weight
from orders o
join items i on i.itemno = o.itemno
group by o.orderno
having count(case when i.location = 'Yard' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when i.location = 'Warehouse' then 1 end) = 0
order by o.orderno;
```

And if you want an aggregation per item, you might need the subquery plus a separate aggregation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I modified that first one to end up with what I needed